# Convert bulk .xlsx files to .csv (UTF-8) in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am new to Pentaho. I am trying to build a transformation that can convert a bunch of .xlsx files to .csv (utf-8).
I tried Get file Names and Text File Output, but it saves a single file as csv and the content of that file is the file properties.
I also tried Microsoft Excel Input and Microsoft Excel Output and that did not work either.

Any help will be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: Do you want all .xlsx files to ONE csv file?

Comment: @glen_11 Could you please elaborate the Issue Properly

Comment: @Runa No, I want all the .xlsx files to be converted into separate .csv files.

Comment: That's ok. I have already given a solution which will convert all the .xlsx files into separate .CSV files. As you said you are new in PDI. Thus my suggestion will be try to understand my given solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have prepare a [SOLUTION](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LEh5LHi1vzunKZEqa5Iv-E0FxWGwNcFU?usp=sharing) for you. I have made my solution full dynamic. For that reason solution is combination of 6 (transformation & job). You only need to define following 2 things:-

1. Source **folder** location
2. Destination **folder** location

Others will work dynamically.

[image]

Also, I have learn a lot with this solution.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sakil Ahmmed, thanks for sharing the solution! I tried this but it created csv files in the destination folder with completely different data in them. Am I supposed to mention the column headers somewhere?

Comment: Not you don't require to mentioned any column headers.Can you please share your sample one .xlsx file or your solution what you tried with me? I was also attached some sample .xlsx file with my solution , so you can run my soultion and can see the csv output (for understanding)

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to generate a separate CSV for each Excel file?
It is better to do it like this:

1. Using the Get File Names component, read the list of Excel files from the folder.
2. Then call Execute Transformation, and pass the name of the file.

Then a separate Transformation will be performed for each file, and a separate CSV will be generated in it for each Excel file.