# Upload multiple files to pentaho

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

In pentaho data integration, how do I import a list of xlsx files that are in the same folder?

note: the number of columns are always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your excel column name and sheet name are always same then you can use **[THIS](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R6dU8CRTQ3Y5WgHN-WzgdnG6ZHjUxxf_?usp=sharing)** solution. Here I have take all xlsx file from source folder and convert one-by-one file as csv.
[image]

But if your excel columnname and sheet name are dynamic or you need some dynamic solution. Then you can use my another stackoverflow solution from **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66768638/convert-bulk-xlsx-files-to-csv-utf-8-in-pentaho/66780102#66780102)**