# Pentaho: Multiple excel in folder to a excel

Tags: excel, merge, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I've successfully input multiple Microsoft Excel files from a folder. How can I save all of them into one Excel file?

referensi input : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66865749/23392458

I want all Excel files within that folder can be accessed within one Microsoft Excel

Answer (score 1):

In PDI, you can "append" rows to a Microsoft Excel Output steps. By checking the option "Append" (as shown below); you can read the input excel files and write to one single file with the append option enabled. This will bring all the records into one single file.

[image]